# Кольцо и перстень

Tags: синонимы

И кольцо, и перстень обозначают в принципе одно и то же: украшение, надеваемое на палец.
Только при слове "перстень" мы представляем себе некое массивное сооружение, чаще мужское, а кольцо - это нечто более нежное, явно женское.
Но при этом я слышала употребление слово "кольцо" по отношению к вполне мужским и крупным изделиям (вспомним хотя бы те же толкинеские кольца - и не только Всевластья), при этом, наоборот, вполне женские называли "перстенек".
А все-таки есть смысловая разница между словами "кольцо" (в плане украшения) и "перстень"?

Comment: Сами  же  видите,  что  на  сегодняшний  день  это,  практически,  синонимы.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала разберёмся с происхождением данных слов: перстень происходит от "перст" - палец, "кольцо" - коло - окружность. Перст - анатомическая единица, коло - геометрическая(и даже астрономическая - кольца Сатурна, галактические кольца...). 
Кольцо является перстнем с точки зрения анатомии, перстень кольцом - с точки зрения геометрии. Но перстень, как вы правильно заметили, действительно, нечто более массивное, ибо к кольцу добавлены некие другие формы.

Comment: Кольцо - признак зависимости, перстень - признак богатства и достатка.

Answer (score 1):

Всегда считала, что перстень - это кольцо с камнем. А собственно кольцо - без.  Получается, что кольцо - более широкое понятие, чем перстень.

Хочу добавить. Посмотрела в словарях. В толковых Ушакова, Ефремовой, Ожегова и др. перстень - это кольцо именно с камнем. Для кольца же камень совсем не обязателен.

Comment: Перстень - это ещё и "кольцо с печаткой", "кольцо с украшением в виде соединённых рук" и, даже, нелепая конструкция, выглядящая как "суставчатый напальчник с когтем на конце".

А есть ещё "прорезные" перстни (держатся на пальце с помощью двух дуг), перстни в виде спирали (как правило, украшенной стразами) и ряд других наперстных украшений, в которых кольца вообще нет.

Comment: Я бы кольца со всякими дополнительными массивными частями (камни, какие-то доп элементы из того же металла или другого) отнесла бы к перстням. А спиралевидные или другой какой-либо формы, но плоские все же к кольцам.

Comment: "Кольцо" - это геометрическая фигура. Вполне определённой формы.

Наперстное украшение в виде кольца называется "кольцом" именно по форме.

Наперстное украшение с печатью называется "печатка".

Наперстное украшение в виде спирали - "змейка".

Есть свои названия и у некоторых других видов наперстных украшений.

И **все** эти украшения называются "перстнями" - по месту ношения.



Другое дело, что форма "кольцо" является преобладающей. И именно по этой причине иногда "перстень в виде кольца" ошибочно противопоставляется просто "перстню".

Comment: Очень интересное разделение! Я в хорошем смысле. А гвоздь согнутый будет спиралевидным перстнем? (Это не издевка я действительно видела такой у доктора-рокера. Перстень в форме гвоздя, обернутого вокруг пальца. Не знаю, насколько он удобен, но оригинален).
  Как, например, тогда быть с обручальными кольцами (без дополнений)? По месту ношения это, по-вашему, перстень. Но я бы назвала исключительно кольцом.

Comment: Скрученный гвоздь - всё та-же "змейка". Просто не в меру оригинальная.
Что же касается колец... Я уже писал, что "кольцо" - самая распространённая форма наперстных украшений. Именно по этой причине в сочетании "перстень-кольцо" (как "перстень-печатка") слово "перстень" обычно опускают. Так-что смело можете и дальше называть "кольца" "кольцами"... Просто не следует противопоставлять часть целому.

Answer (score 0):

Скажем так, "кольцо" - одна из форм "перстня", который есть "наперстное украшение". Причём, все остальные формы "перстня" окажутся более массивными, чем "кольцо".

Answer (score 0):

Небольшой экскурс в родственные языки.

На территории бывшей Югославии и Чехословакии (напишу так, вместо списка новых стран :-)) слово "палец" звучит почти как старо-славянское "перст". Но **пишется забавно**, совсем без гласных, **"prst"**. Читается как "пэрст" или "пырст". А перстень у них - это всё что одевается на перст. Хоть с камнем, хоть без, толстое и тонкое.

[[@Надюшка](/users/308/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0)](/users/308/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0) пишет:

> Всегда считала, что перстень - это кольцо с камнем. А собственно кольцо - без. Получается, что кольцо - более широкое понятие, чем перстень.

Я именно эти слова сказал одному хорвату. Он очень удивился и спросил: "**А почему именно с камнем?**". Я так до сих пор и не знаю, что ответить на вопрос. :-)
У них-то логика понятная - украшение для пальца и всё. А в русском языке?

Здесь, если интересно, можно послушать, как произносится **prst**.
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prst

P.S.
[[@Fuchoin Kazuki](/users/3/fuchoin-kazuki)](/users/3/fuchoin-kazuki) пишет:

> вспомним хотя бы те же толкинеские кольца - и не только Всевластья), при этом, наоборот, вполне женские называли "перстенек"

:-) А "Властелин Колец" в Хорватии называется приблизительно (точно до буквы не помню, могу чуть-чуть неграмотно написать) -- "Господар пэрстнив".

P.P.S. Проверил, точное написание "Gospodar prstenova".